# How do I unit test an action that returns a ToList

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello I'm trying to run some tests for this Controller Method but I'm struggling to test the View, here's my controller class.

```
public class StockController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStockService _stockService;

    public StockController(IStockService stockService)
    {
        _stockService = stockService;
    }

    // GET: Stock
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IEnumerable<StockDto> stocks = null;
        try
        {
            stocks = await _stockService.GetStockAsync();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            stocks = Array.Empty<StockDto>();
        }
        return View(stocks.ToList());
    }
}
```

Here is the Test Method on the MS Test Project for the Stock Controller, I've got the *Arrange* and *Act* working fine, but for the *Asserts* there is a red line on the 'ViewResult' and I'm not sure why.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReturnIndexMethod()
{
    //Arrange
    var controller = new StockController(new FakeStockService());
    //Act
    var result = await controller.Index(); 
    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    var AResult = result as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(AResult);
    var stockResult = AResult.Value as IEnumerable<StockDto>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(stockResult);

}
```

Also here is the `FakeStockService` that will supply mock test Data just in case people need to see it.

```
public class FakeStockService : IStockService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<StockDto> _stock = new List<StockDto>
    {
        new StockDto { Id = 1, Name = "asfdaf", Description = "afsdfsfdsda", Price = 5000 }
    };

    public Task<IEnumerable<StockDto>> GetStockAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_stock);
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, I've just come at a loss here after trying everything else.

Comment: Unless that is a typo, the view result should have a Model property, not Value like you have there. Everything else looks fine to me. What is the error message? Maybe the test is missing a namespace in order to access that View Result type.

Comment: I didn't have an error for it but I changed it to 

var stockResult = AResult.ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<StockDto>; and that seems to work better, the ViewResult had a redline and it's telling me to change it to "as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult;" instead, but I'm not sure why, that doesn't seem to work either. And thank you for replying Nkosi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the test is missing the namespace in order to access that `ViewResult` type.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//...
```

Also, unless that is a typo, the view result should have a `Model` property, not `Value` like you have there.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ReturnIndexMethod()
{
    //Arrange
    var controller = new StockController(new FakeStockService());

    //Act
    var result = await controller.Index(); 

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    var view = result as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(view);
    var stockResult = view.Model as IEnumerable<StockDto>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(stockResult);
}
```

Everything else in the test looks fine to me.

The controller action however appears to be accessing model state on a GET request. The current example shown does not any obvious need to use the model state so I would suggest removing that

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    IEnumerable<StockDto> stocks = null;
    try {
        stocks = await _stockService.GetStockAsync();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException) {
        stocks = Array.Empty<StockDto>();
    }
    return View(stocks.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was help but strangely enough the ViewResult still has an error, and I do have the mvc namespace like you suggested, the up to date package. 

VS tells me to change it to "as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult;" and it appears to work, strange though! 

And I deleted ModelRequest, thank you for suggesting that, not sure why I had it I'm just used to it. I also changed it to Model instead of Value.